# OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory pStep = subprocess.Popen(cmdline)

Tags: python

When I try to test the sample of openmvs, I got the following error:

```
dxq@dxq-great:~/openMVS_sample-master$ python ./MvgMvs_Pipeline.py /home/dxq/ImageDataset_ /home/dxq/8

 # Using input dir  :  /home/dxq/ImageDataset_
    #       output_dir :  /home/dxq/8
    # First step  :  0
    # Last step :  11
    #0. Intrinsics analysis
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "./MvgMvs_Pipeline.py", line 236, in <module>
        pStep = subprocess.Popen(cmdline)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
        errread, errwrite)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1343, in _execute_child
        raise child_exception
    OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

the following is the code of MvgMvs_Pipeline.py.some codes likely go wrong. But I don't know where it is wrong. I know that the path of Python is wrong, but what I need to do about the code of MvgMvs_Pipeline.py.

```
import commands
import os
import subprocess
import sys

# Indicate the openMVG and openMVS binary directories
OPENMVG_BIN = "D:/Pro/OpenMVG/install/bin/"
OPENMVS_BIN = "D:/Pro/OpenMVS/install/bin/"

# Indicate the openMVG camera sensor width directory
CAMERA_SENSOR_WIDTH_DIRECTORY = OPENMVG_BIN

DEBUG=False

## HELPERS for terminal colors
BLACK, RED, GREEN, YELLOW, BLUE, MAGENTA, CYAN, WHITE = range(8)
NO_EFFECT, BOLD, UNDERLINE, BLINK, INVERSE, HIDDEN = (0,1,4,5,7,8)

#from Python cookbook, #475186
def has_colours(stream):
    if not hasattr(stream, "isatty"):
        return False
    if not stream.isatty():
        return False # auto color only on TTYs
    try:
        import curses
        curses.setupterm()
        return curses.tigetnum("colors") > 2
    except:
        # guess false in case of error
        return False
has_colours = has_colours(sys.stdout)

def printout(text, colour=WHITE, background=BLACK, effect=NO_EFFECT):
        if has_colours:
                seq = "\x1b[%d;%d;%dm" % (effect, 30+colour, 40+background) + text + "\x1b[0m"
                sys.stdout.write(seq+'\r\n')
        else:
                sys.stdout.write(text+'\r\n')

## OBJECTS to store config and data in

class ConfContainer(object):
    """Container for all the config variables"""
    pass

conf=ConfContainer()

class aStep:
    def __init__(self, info, cmd, opt):
        self.info = info
        self.cmd = cmd
        self.opt = opt

class stepsStore :
    def __init__(self):
        self.steps_data=[
            [   "Intrinsics analysis",
                os.path.join(OPENMVG_BIN,"openMVG_main_SfMInit_ImageListing"),
                ["-i", "%input_dir%", "-o", "%matches_dir%", "-d", "%camera_file_params%"] ],
            [   "Compute features",
                os.path.join(OPENMVG_BIN,"openMVG_main_ComputeFeatures"),
                ["-i", "%matches_dir%/sfm_data.json", "-o", "%matches_dir%", "-m", "SIFT", "-n", "4"] ],
            [   "Compute matches",
                os.path.join(OPENMVG_BIN, "openMVG_main_ComputeMatches"),
                ["-i", "%matches_dir%/sfm_data.json", "-o", "%matches_dir%"] ],
            [   "Incremental reconstruction",
                os.path.join(OPENMVG_BIN, "openMVG_main_IncrementalSfM"),
                ["-i", "%matches_dir%/sfm_data.json", "-m", "%matches_dir%", "-o", "%reconstruction_dir%"] ],
            [   "Colorize Structure",
                os.path.join(OPENMVG_BIN,"openMVG_main_ComputeSfM_DataColor"),
                ["-i", "%reconstruction_dir%/sfm_data.bin", "-o", "%reconstruction_dir%/colorized.ply"]],
            [   "Structure from Known Poses",
                os.path.join(OPENMVG_BIN,"openMVG_main_ComputeStructureFromKnownPoses"),
                ["-i", "%reconstruction_dir%/sfm_data.bin", "-m", "%matches_dir%", "-f", "%matches_dir%/matches.f.bin", "-o", "%reconstruction_dir%/robust.bin"]],
            [   "Colorized robust triangulation",
                os.path.join(OPENMVG_BIN,"openMVG_main_ComputeSfM_DataColor"),
                ["-i", "%reconstruction_dir%/robust.bin", "-o", "%reconstruction_dir%/robust_colorized.ply"]],
            [   "Export to openMVS",
                os.path.join(OPENMVG_BIN,"openMVG_main_openMVG2openMVS"),
                ["-i", "%reconstruction_dir%/sfm_data.bin", "-o", "%mvs_dir%/scene.mvs","-d","%mvs_dir%"]],
            [   "Densify point cloud",
                os.path.join(OPENMVS_BIN,"DensifyPointCloud"),
                ["scene.mvs", "-w","%mvs_dir%"]],
            [   "Reconstruct the mesh",
                os.path.join(OPENMVS_BIN,"ReconstructMesh"),
                ["scene_dense.mvs", "-w","%mvs_dir%"]],
            [   "Refine the mesh",
                os.path.join(OPENMVS_BIN,"RefineMesh"),
                ["scene_dense_mesh.mvs", "-w","%mvs_dir%"]],
            [   "Texture the mesh",
                os.path.join(OPENMVS_BIN,"TextureMesh"),
                ["scene_dense_mesh_refine.mvs", "-w","%mvs_dir%"]]
            ]

    def __getitem__(self, indice):
        return aStep(*self.steps_data[indice])

    def length(self):
        return len(self.steps_data)

    def apply_conf(self, conf):
        """ replace each %var% per conf.var value in steps data """
        for s in self.steps_data :
            o2=[]
            for o in s[2]:
                co=o.replace("%input_dir%",conf.input_dir)
                co=co.replace("%output_dir%",conf.output_dir)
                co=co.replace("%matches_dir%",conf.matches_dir)
                co=co.replace("%reconstruction_dir%",conf.reconstruction_dir)
                co=co.replace("%mvs_dir%",conf.mvs_dir)
                co=co.replace("%camera_file_params%",conf.camera_file_params)
                o2.append(co)
            s[2]=o2

steps=stepsStore()

## ARGS
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
    description="Photogrammetry reconstruction with these steps : \r\n"+
        "\r\n".join(("\t%i. %s\t %s" % (t, steps[t].info, steps[t].cmd) for t in range(steps.length())))
    )
parser.add_argument('input_dir', help="the directory which contains the pictures set.")
parser.add_argument('output_dir', help="the directory which will contain the resulting files.")
parser.add_argument('-f','--first_step', type=int, default=0, help="the first step to process")
parser.add_argument('-l','--last_step', type=int, default=11, help="the last step to process" )

group = parser.add_argument_group('Passthrough',description="Option to be passed to command lines (remove - in front of option names)\r\ne.g. --1 p ULTRA to use the ULTRA preset in openMVG_main_ComputeFeatures")
for n in range(steps.length()) :
    group.add_argument('--'+str(n), nargs='+')

parser.parse_args(namespace=conf) #store args in the ConfContainer

## FOLDERS

def mkdir_ine(dirname):
    """Create the folder if not presents"""
    if not os.path.exists(dirname):
        os.mkdir(dirname)

#Absolute path for input and ouput dirs
conf.input_dir=os.path.abspath(conf.input_dir)
conf.output_dir=os.path.abspath(conf.output_dir)

if not os.path.exists(conf.input_dir):
    sys.exit("%s : path not found" % conf.input_dir)


conf.matches_dir = os.path.join(conf.output_dir, "matches")
conf.reconstruction_dir = os.path.join(conf.output_dir, "reconstruction_sequential")
conf.mvs_dir = os.path.join(conf.output_dir, "mvs")
conf.camera_file_params = os.path.join(CAMERA_SENSOR_WIDTH_DIRECTORY, "sensor_width_camera_database.txt")

mkdir_ine(conf.output_dir)
mkdir_ine(conf.matches_dir)
mkdir_ine(conf.reconstruction_dir)
mkdir_ine(conf.mvs_dir)

steps.apply_conf(conf)

## WALK
print "# Using input dir  :  %s" % conf.input_dir
print "#       output_dir :  %s" % conf.output_dir
print "# First step  :  %i" % conf.first_step
print "# Last step :  %i" % conf.last_step
for cstep in range(conf.first_step, conf.last_step+1):
    printout("#%i. %s" % (cstep, steps[cstep].info), effect=INVERSE)

    opt=getattr(conf,str(cstep))
    if opt is not None :
        #add - sign to short options and -- to long ones
        for o in range(0,len(opt),2):
            if len(opt[o])>1:
                opt[o]='-'+opt[o]
            opt[o]='-'+opt[o]
    else:
        opt=[]

    #Remove steps[cstep].opt options now defined in opt
    for anOpt in steps[cstep].opt :
        if anOpt in opt :
            idx=steps[cstep].opt.index(anOpt)
            if DEBUG :
                print '#\t'+'Remove '+ str(anOpt) + ' from defaults options at id ' + str(idx)
            del steps[cstep].opt[idx:idx+2]

    cmdline = [steps[cstep].cmd] + steps[cstep].opt + opt

    if not DEBUG :
        pStep = subprocess.Popen(cmdline)
        pStep.wait()
    else:
        print '\t'+' '.join(cmdline)
```

I know that there is some wrong about of Python, but I don't know how to deal with it.

Comment: It might help if you showed us the code in `MvgMvs_Pipeline.py`.

Comment: Do `/home/dxq/ImageDataset_` and `/home/dxq/8` exist?  Are they directories or files?

Comment: they are directories@John Gordon

Comment: Try setting `DEBUG=True` at the top of the script.  That will print the command instead of executing it.  Hopefully when you see the command, the error will be obvious.

Comment: The error specifically means that the first argument in `cmdline` was not an executable that exists. It's thus `steps[cstep].cmd` that you should be investigating most closely.